# Batch script to copy folder not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I wish to setup a batch file to copy a folder (from the same location of the batch file) to the Microsoft folder in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming to be used by Outlook for email signatures.

The batch file currently looks like:

```
@echo off

ROBOCOPY \Files "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft" /COPYALL /MIR
regedit.exe /s Setup-File-Linking.reg
```

It imports the registry setting fine, but does not copy the "Signatures" folder across.

**I have the wrong source path.  How do I make it relative to where the script is being run from?**

In the folder where the batch file is run from, the file structure looks like:

```
FOLDER
|- Run Me!.bat
|- Setup-File-Linking.reg
|- Files *(dir)*
   |- Signatures *(dir)*
      |- emailsignature.htm
      |- emailsignature.rtf
      |- emailsignature.txt
      |- emailsignature_files *(dir)*
         |- colorschememapping.xml
         |- filelist.xml
         |- themedata.thmx
___
```

.

***--- EDIT ---***

I added `pause` to the end of my script to see any errors.
A screenshot is below.  I've edited my question above to suit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the /S option to the ROBOCOPY command.
See ROBOCOPY /?

Replace the source (\Files) with "%CD%\Files"
I think you still need the /S

Added 9/19/2014
To verify that the user has admin privileges you can do something like this.

```
REM Do OPENFILES to verify that user has administrative privileges
OPENFILES >nul 2>nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  COLOR CF
  ECHO.You must run this program as administrator
  PAUSE
  GOTO :eof
  )
```

Comment: that didn't help.  I added pause to the script so I can see any errors.  I've updated my question to suit.

Comment: I'll try that.
I also tried using %~dp0\Files and it actually deleted everything out of the Microsoft directory (saying *EXTRA FILE*).  I think I need to remove the /MIR.   LOL!
How can I overcome permissions errors when some systems may have UAC enabled and forget to "Run as administrator"??

Comment: using %CD% and /S works.  I needed to remove /copyall as well as /mir from the command.
Thanks.

Comment: Added to my answer to address your "Run as administrator" concern.